# Exchange EWS Coldfusion - need to convert WebDav to EWS

Tags: coldfusion, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

I've managed to connect to my exchange server via EWS and send an email.  I need an example of how to create a calendar item.

Coldfusion 9
Exchange 2007

```
<cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService" name="service">
<cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeVersion" name="version">
<cfset service.init(version.Exchange2007_SP1)>
<cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.WebCredentials" name="credentials">
<cfset credentials.init("z@x.com","password")>
<cfset service.setCredentials(credentials) />
<cfobject type="Java" class="java.net.URI" name="uri">
<cfset uri.init("server URL")>
<cfset service.setUrl(uri) />
<cfobject type="Java" action="create" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.EmailMessage" name="message">
<cfset message = message.init(service) />
<cfset message.SetSubject("EWSTest")>
<cfset messageBody = CreateObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.MessageBody")>
<cfset messageBody.init("My EWS test message again")>
<cfset message.SetBody( messageBody )>
<cfset message.ToRecipients.Add("email@gmail.com") >
<cfset message.SendAndSaveCopy() >
```

I tried the following code but only got an error that only says "Subject";

```
<cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService" name="appointment">
<cfset appointment.Subject = "Dentist Appointment">
<cfset appointment.Body = "The appointment is with Dr. Smith.">
<cfset appointment.Start = createDateTime(Year('2014/03/22'), Month('2014/03/22'), 
 Day('2014/03/22'), Hour('09:00'), Minute('09:00'), 0)>
<cfset appointment.End = createDateTime(Year('2014/03/22'), Month('2014/03/22'), 
 Day('2014/03/22'), Hour('09:00'), Minute('09:00'), 0)>
<cfset appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone)>
```

(edit) - current code:

```
    <cfset StartDateTime = createDateTime(Year('2014/03/22'), Month('2014/03/22'), Day('2014/03/22'), Hour('09:00'), Minute('09:00'), 0)>
<cfset EndDateTime = createDateTime(Year('2014/03/22'), Month('2014/03/22'), Day('2014/03/22'), Hour('09:30'), Minute('09:30'), 0)>
<cfscript>
    exchangeService = createObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService");
    exchangeVersion = createObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeVersion");
    service = exchangeService.init(exchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
    webCredentials = createObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.WebCredentials");
    service.setCredentials(webCredentials.init("z@x.com","password"));
    serviceURI = createObject("java", "java.net.URI").init("https://owa016.msoutlookonline.net/EWS/Exchange.asmx?wsdl"));
    service.setUrl(serviceURI);
    appointment = createObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Appointment").init(service);
    appointment.Start = "#StartDateTime#";
appointment.End = "#EndDateTime#";
    appointment.Subject = "Dentist Appointment";
    appointment.Body = "The appointment is with Dr. Smith.";
    appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
</cfscript>
```

(edit 2) - partial solution;

```
<cfset StartDateTime = createDateTime(Year('2014/03/22'), Month('2014/03/22'), Day('2014/03/22'), Hour('09:00'), Minute('09:00'), 0)>
<cfset EndDateTime = createDateTime(Year('2014/03/22'), Month('2014/03/22'), Day('2014/03/22'), Hour('09:30'), Minute('09:30'), 0)>
<!--- <cfoutput>Start=#StartDateTime#<br>End=#EndDateTime#</cfoutput><cfabort> --->
<cfscript>
    exchangeService = createObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService");
    exchangeVersion = createObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeVersion");
    service = exchangeService.init(exchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
    webCredentials = createObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.WebCredentials");
    service.setCredentials(webCredentials.init("z@x.com","password"));
    serviceURI = createObject("java", "java.net.URI").init("https://owa016.msoutlookonline.net/EWS/Exchange.asmx?wsdl");
    service.setUrl(serviceURI);
    appointment = createObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Appointment").init(service);
    appointment.setStartTimeZone(microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.TimeZoneDefinition)
    appointment.setStart("#StartDateTime#");
    appointment.setEnd("#EndDateTime#");
    appointment.setSubject("Dentist Appointment");
    MessageBody = createObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.MessageBody");
    appointment.setBody( MessageBody.init("The appointment is with Dr. Smith.") );
    SendInvitationsMode = createObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.SendInvitationsMode");
    appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
</cfscript>
```

This is the error I got; 
StartTimeZone required when setting the Start, End, IsAllDayEvent, or Recurrence properties. You must load or assign this property before attempting to update the appointment.

That sounds like Exchange 2010 and I'm on Exchange 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Too long for comments ...)

Though not a complete answer, a few observations about the code:

- When working with java objects, the true error is often contained in the stack trace, rather than the error header. Always check the stack trace too. In this case it reports

  `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: SUBJECT`
   `at coldfusion.runtime.StructBean.bindName(StructBean.java:243)`

- The most likely reason for that error is that you are using the wrong type of object. The properties you are attempting to set do not exist in the `ExchangeService` class. I believe you need to create an instance of an `Appointment` object instead, which does have the subject, startdate, etcetera properties. Similar to what is shown in this [C# example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633661%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx).

  (Side note, personally I prefer cfscript for java code as the syntax is very similar. Using your original example as a base, something along these lines:)

  ```
  exchangeService = createObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService");
  exchangeVersion = createObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeVersion");
  service = exchangeService.init(exchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);

  webCredentials = createObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.WebCredentials");
  service.setCredentials(webCredentials.init("z@x.com","password") );

  serviceURI = createObject("java", "java.net.URI").init("server URL");
  service.setUrl(serviceURI);

  appointment = createObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Appointment").init(service);
  // ... set subject, date, etcetera properties
  ```
- If you are using C# examples as a base, keep in mind the syntax does not always translate exactly. In theory, CF supports direct assignment of properties using the syntax below,  but only if ["[the] class conforms to the JavaBeans pattern."](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec14231-7fdd.html#WSAA477E61-1C72-47bb-9632-88C25FC93762):

  `<cfset appointment.Subject = "Dentist Appointment">`

  That may not be case with the EWS classes. You may need to invoke the methods explicitly:

  `<cfset appointment.setSubject("Dentist Appointment")>`
- The ["Body" property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.body%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) is not a simple string. You need to create an instance of `microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.MessageBody` instead.
- `SendInvitationsMode` is also a class. You need to create an instance of it before you can use its properties here:

  `appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);`

Comment: I'm so glad to get a response!  But, I'm almost as confused as when I started.  The following is my latest snippet;

Comment: Sorry!  I don't see the problem.  I thought I was creating an appointment object.

Comment: Nope. You just created an instance of ExchangeService and *named* it appointment: cfobject type="Java" **class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService"** name="**appointment**">. You are still working with the service class. You need to create an instance of the `Appointment` class as well, then set the properties (subject, startdate, etcetera) on *that* object.

Comment: Can you append your current code to [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22566437/edit)?

Comment: I'm getting the following error;

You must load or assign this property before you can read its value.

It's in the statement;

appointment.Start = "#StartDateTime#";

Comment: (Edit) Yes, you still need to fix the code mentioned in the last three (3) bullet points. As I mentioned above, you may not be able to set those properties directly. Instead you may need to call the methods explicitly ie Instead of `appointment.PropertyName = 'foo'` use `appointment.setPropertyName('foo')`. Join chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50206/question-22566437