# convert EWS code to coldfusion

Tags: c#, coldfusion, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm not sure what language "using" is from, but what would the Coldfusion equivalent be?

```
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service);
appointment.Subject = subject;
appointment.Start = DateTime.Parse(StartDate);
appointment.End = DateTime.Parse(EndDate);
appointment.IsReminderSet = false;
appointment.Save();
```

Comment: take a look at the <cfexchange* tags: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec17576-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-75be - they handle connecting and interacting with Exchange

Comment: CFexchange tags won't work for me.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm curious, why won't they work for you?

Comment: I'm using CF9, Exchange 2007, and EWS API 1.2  and WebDav is required. The ISP that hosts the Exchange server doesn't have WebDav enabled.

Comment: _I'm not sure what language "using" is from..._ - where did you get this code from?

Comment: I tried to back track, but couldn't find it again.

Comment: the first line is telling it to use a library, that would contain the various objects needed for the code and then some.  The second line is instantiating an object with a service, i don't know what `service` is, but it's an eqiv of `CreateObject("component",blah)`.  3-6 are getters and setters and 7 saves the object.  that's the CFEquiv

Comment: Yes, it is C#. You do not need the `using ...` clause statement in CF because the path information is supplied in your `createObject()` statements instead, as Jarede mentioned. That snippet is almost exactly the same as [what you were doing before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566437/exchange-ews-coldfusion-need-to-convert-webdav-to-ews). Only with an extra property and a different `save()` method. So it may not behave any differently. I am swamped today, but maybe someone else can help using the details on the other thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran in to this question because i needed to solve a credentials problem with the EWS API. I included my Coldfusion code solution. I have this working with CF 9.1 and CF 10.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
    <head>
        <title>EWS test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <cfoutput>
            <!--- Init the credentials and serversettings for testing--->
            <!---
                The username can be any of the following formats depending on the AD settings
                ewstest
                ewstest@myDomain
                ewstest\ADdomain
        --->
        <cfset myUsername   = "ewstest" >
        <cfset myPassword   = "*******" >
        <!---
            The ADdomain must mach. It might not be the same as the e-mail domainname.
        --->
        <cfset myDomain     = "ADdomain" >
        <cfset myServer     = "owaserver" >

        <cfset theRecipient = "test@test.com">

    </cfoutput>
    <cfoutput>
    <!--- 
                Author  : Lion van Koppenhagen
                Version : 1.5
                Notes       : This sollution is shared by me at adobe.com at 2011-08-22
                                    To allow developers to work with this sollution, Adobe included the needed libraries in Coldfusion 10.0 and up.

                Description
                ===========
            With Exchange 2007 Microsoft abandoned WebDav as an interface to Exchangeserver.
            The standard Coldfusion Tags relied on WebDav and will not work anymore.

            Since I needed a way to interface with Exchange Server I started looking for possible solutions and this is what I came up with.

            In december 2010 Microsoft released the Exchange Managed Services Library for java.
            You can find it here: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=5691

            In the getting started document it tells you it depends on 4 3rd party libraries which you need to be download separately:
                -    Apache Commons HttpClient 3.1 (commons-httpclient-3.1.jar)
                -    Apache Commons Codec 1.4 (commons-codec-1.4.jar)
                -    Apache Commons Logging 1.1.1 (commons-codec-1.4.jar)
                -    JCIFS 1.3.15 (jcifs-1.3.15.jar)

            With Coldfusion 9.1 (the version I tested with) you only need
                -    JCIFS 1.3.15 (jcifs-1.3.15.jar) which you can download here: http://jcifs.samba.org/src/

            Place the EWS Jar and the JCIFS Jar in your Coldfusion libray folder and after restarting CF server the following code should work.                         

                With Coldfusion 10.0 the JCIFS jar and EWS jar are standard installed in the lib directory.

                Additional notes
                ================
                2015-05-01
                While testing this sollution against a new customer a ran into a 401 access denied error.
                After debugging with our client we found out the domain used to verify the credentials must match the internal AD domain.
        --->
        <!--- 1. I need an instance of the ExchangeService class --->
        <cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService" name="service">
        <cfset service.init()>

        <!--- 2.  I need to set the credentials --->
        <!--- 2a. Create an instance of the WebCredentials class --->
        <cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.WebCredentials" name="credentials">
        <!--- 2b. Set the credentials --->
        <cfset credentials.init("#myUsername#","#myPassword#", "#myDomain")>
        <!--- 2c. Set the credentials in the service object --->
        <cfset service.setCredentials(credentials) />

        <!--- 3.  In need to set the URL to Exchange (stay away from autodsicovery) --->
        <!--- 3a. Create an instance of the Uri class --->
        <cfobject type="Java" class="java.net.URI" name="uri">
        <!--- 3b. Set the full path --->
        <cfset uri.init("https://#myServer#/ews/exchange.asmx")>
        <!--- 3c. Set the url in the service object --->
        <cfset service.setUrl(uri) />

        <!--- These are the steps you need to create valid a service object. --->

        <!--- Now we need to do something with it. --->
        <!--- I create a test message to my own mailbox to see if it works --->
        <cfobject type="Java" action="create" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.EmailMessage" name="message">
        <cfset message = message.init(service) />
        <cfset message.SetSubject("EWSTest")>

        <cfset messageBody = CreateObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.MessageBody")>
        <cfset messageBody.init("My EWS test message")>

        <cfset message.SetBody( messageBody )>

        <cfset message.ToRecipients.Add("#theRecipient#") >


        #message.SendAndSaveCopy()#
    </cfoutput>
</body>
```